# Woocommerce price update via REST API: Update prices if product doesn't tagged with EOL

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I update prices via woocommerce REST API.
I send command to update all prices.
My website have some discontinued = EOL products.
I plan to add "EOL" tag to these products.
I am trying to make a command "Update all prices if products are not tagged as EOL"

Is there a command like this in REST API?